# Dragging and Dropping QGraphicItems - position not displaying correctly

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm making a drop and drag interface in PyQT, and when I drag and drop and object into my main QGraphicsView, I'm trying to draw that object at that point where it is dropped.

```
    def dropEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()
        newobject = Object()
        newobject.setPos(e.pos())
        self.scene.addItem(newobject)
```

the Object() class is a QGraphicsItem which has its own paint and boundingRect methods.  I'm representing my QStandardItems in a QStandardItemModel.

Now, when I drag an drop an Object onto my QGraphicsView, I've found that the location at which it is drawn is not necessarily consistent with where the mouse was positioned when I dropped the item.  I am confused because I thought that the:

```
 newobject.setPos(e.pos())
```

command would set the position of the object to exactly where it was dropped, so it would be drawn in that location as well. Can anyone suggest to me why It might not be showing up in the correct location?

Comment: Where exactly is the item placed? E.g. Bottom right of the mouse position? Keep in mind `setPos()` sets the location of the `(0|0)` coordinate of the item which could be e.g. the top left corner of the item dependent on how you created it.

Comment: No, it seems to be placed at a very different position - many times the size of the object off.  For example, if I placed it at 100,0... it might show up at 500,500 even though the size of the object is only 40x40.  Also there doesn't seem to be a distinct pattern to how it is off.